# On click only one accordion should open

Tags: jquery

when I click on red box all ".community-sub-row" open, I want when I click on red box only one ".community-sub-row" shoud open at a time and other should close. Thanks in advance. And in red box i have used arrow-right and arrow-down toggle class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".community-sub-row").hide();

  $(".community-toggle-arrow").click(function(){
    $(".community-sub-row").slideToggle();
    $(".community-toggle-arrow span").toggleClass("ion-arrow-right-b");
  });
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/alpeshlahad/md528n6y/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following. Use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the parent row and then show/hide the items.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".community-sub-row").hide();
  $(".community-toggle-arrow").click(function() {
    var that = this;
    if(!$(that).hasClass('progress')){
      $(that).addClass('progress');
      $thisRows = $(that).closest('.community-row').find(".community-sub-row");
      $(".community-sub-row").not($thisRows).slideUp(); 
      $thisRows.slideToggle(function(){
          $(that).removeClass('progress');
      });
      $(that).find("span").toggleClass("ion-arrow-down-b ion-arrow-right-b");
    }
  });
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/md528n6y/10/)**

Comment: Thanks Rejith, it work as I want, I have one more thing, in red box I used arrow class, which not support to jsfiddle, how to manage them when it open right-arrow active and when close down-arrow active.

Comment: @JavaScriptbeginner...: thats because jsfiddle does not have that specific css class ( `ion-arrow-down-b` & `ion-arrow-right-b`) which your referring in your code

Comment: Yes friend I know, but when I click all span toggle, your code is excellent for me, just need to toggleClass("ion-arrow-right-b") only for current open div.

Comment: Thanks  a lot :) you made my day.

Comment: @JavaScriptbeginner... I added one more improvement, could be useful in the cases of multiple clicks.

Comment: @JavaScriptbeginner...: hey if you have found your solution then,can you close this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to toggle the `community-sub-row` element within the same `community-row`.

Also use a css rule to set the default display state of `community-sub-row`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $subs = $(".community-sub-row");

  $(".community-toggle-arrow").click(function() {
    var $sub = $(this).closest('.community-row').find(".community-sub-row").stop(true).slideToggle();
    $subs.not($sub).stop(true).slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
}
.clearfix {
  display: block;
}
.community-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.community-row .community-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.community-row .community-wrap .community-toggle-arrow {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #2385ca;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
}
.community-row .community-wrap .community-icon {
  float: left;
}
.community-row .community-wrap .community-icon img {
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
}
.community-row .community-wrap .community-title {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}
.community-row .community-wrap .community-title a {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 18px;
}
.community-row .community-wrap .noti-indicator {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  color: #2385ca;
  border: 1px solid #2385ca;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 8px;
  line-height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.community-row .community-sub-row {
  padding: 0 0 0 17px;
}
.community-row .community-sub-row .community-wrap {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.community-row .community-sub-row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="community-row">
  <div class="community-wrap clearfix">
    <div class="community-toggle-arrow"><span class="ion-arrow-down-b"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="community-icon">
      <img src="assets/img/community_sjsu_lg.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="community-title"><a href="#">Mechanical Engineering (SJSU)</a>
    </div>
    <div class="noti-indicator">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="community-sub-row clearfix">
    <div class="community-wrap clearfix">
      <div class="community-icon">
        <img src="assets/img/community_mech_sys.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="community-title"><a href="#">Mechanical Systems</a>
      </div>
      <div class="noti-indicator">5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="community-wrap clearfix">
      <div class="community-icon">
        <img src="assets/img/community_coding.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="community-title"><a href="#">Front-end Coding</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="community-row">
  <div class="community-wrap clearfix">
    <div class="community-toggle-arrow"><span class="ion-arrow-down-b"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="community-icon">
      <img src="assets/img/community_tesla_sm@2x.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="community-title"><a href="#">Tesla Motors</a>
    </div>
    <div class="noti-indicator">20</div>
  </div>
  <div class="community-sub-row clearfix">
    <div class="community-wrap clearfix">
      <div class="community-icon">
        <img src="assets/img/community_mech_sys.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="community-title"><a href="#">Mechanical Systems</a>
      </div>
      <div class="noti-indicator">5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="community-wrap clearfix">
      <div class="community-icon">
        <img src="assets/img/community_coding.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="community-title"><a href="#">Front-end Coding</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="community-row">
  <div class="community-wrap clearfix">
    <div class="community-toggle-arrow"><span class="ion-arrow-down-b"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="community-icon">
      <img src="assets/img/community_foothill_sm@2x.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="community-title"><a href="#">Foothill College</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="community-sub-row clearfix">
    <div class="community-wrap clearfix">
      <div class="community-icon">
        <img src="assets/img/community_mech_sys.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="community-title"><a href="#">Mechanical Systems</a>
      </div>
      <div class="noti-indicator">5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="community-wrap clearfix">
      <div class="community-icon">
        <img src="assets/img/community_coding.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="community-title"><a href="#">Front-end Coding</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There were couple of things missing in your accordion code, which i have fixed below.

- When clicked on arrow, accordion has to expand only the current list and not all, this can be done by referring to current elements parent and then fetching the descendant element `.community-sub-row`.
- Accordion list was not collapsed on load,instead it was happening on `document.ready()`, which was not good, so i added a CSS style to hide the list by default.
- when clicked on accordion it had to collapse all existing accordion first before expanding the current  one.

**JS CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".community-toggle-arrow").click(function() {
    //collapse all accordion before toggling except current
    $('.community-sub-row').not(this).slideUp();
    $(this).closest('.community-row').find(".community-sub-row").slideToggle();
    $(this).find("span").toggleClass("ion-arrow-right-b");
 });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.community-row .community-sub-row {
  padding: 0 0 0 17px;
  display:none; //to hide all accordion on load
}
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/md528n6y/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a unique `id` for every `.community-toggle-arrow` `div` you have, to specific that div you click and have to show.